# Substituting values in the date field (string) within a dataframe

Tags: r, date

It must be a very easy task, but I can't find the right line of code for this:

Data frame (`df`) has several columns (`Date` is the first one, containing string object), and around 200 rows.

```
  Date V1
1 01/01/2011 5
2 02/01/2011 4
3 03/01/2011 2
...
200 05/09/2011
```

needs to become this (current year):

```
  Date V1
1 01/01/2013 5
2 02/01/2013 4
3 03/01/2013 2
...
200 05/09/2013
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're gonna have to give us a bit more detail than that: is `Date` an actual date object or is it just a string? And do all the dates end in 2011 and is the replacement 2013 in every case?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example on making an example that other users can replicate on their machines so they can help you. If your object is `x`, including `dput(head(x))` in your question would be helpful to determine what kind of object you have.

Comment: Just added some edits to my question - please have a look. Thank you

Comment: Hi - this is literally my second post - and I'm a beginner, so might not operate with the right terminology yet. Hope my question is clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df$Date <- sub('11$','13',df$Date)
```

should work.

But beware: naming a variable Date is a bad idea because R already has an internal data type with that name.

Comment: No, didn't work either. Plus reported an error: Error in sub("12$", "13", Date) : object 'Date' not found

Comment: @user10745 RoyalTS was assuming you were familiar with the basics of R and would know how to use a column of a data frame. If what you say in your question is right (i.e. your data.frame's name is `df` and the first column is `Date`, the `Date` column is a character string rather than a `factor` or `Date` object), then `df$Date <- sub('11$', '13', df$Date)` will work. If it doesn't, then you've told us something incorrect. See BlueMagister's comment and link to fix it.

Comment: @user10745 ...and, when you get an answer that works, "accept" it by clicking the checkmark outline to it's left. It thanks the person who answered and let's everyone know you're not still looking for an answer.

Comment: Hi Mike - shujaa's code worked because it WAS actually a string, not a date. I made a mistake in my question - now I know what the difference is. Correcting my post again. Thanks for observation